# Running Groovy class from ANT script

Tags: groovy

I have the following ANT script:

```
<taskdef name="groovy"
    classpath="${antLib}/groovy-all-2.1.3.jar"
    classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" />

<!--<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${antLib}/ant-contrib-0.3.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>-->

<target name="checkout">
        <groovy src="src/name/of/plugin/Checkout.groovy">
            def checkoutClass = new Checkout()
            checkoutClass.init = {-> true}
            <arg line="pom.xml"/>
            <arg line="${svn.root}"/>
            <arg line="${svn.project.dir}"/>
            <arg line="${env.WORKSPACE}"/>
            <arg line="${svnLib}"/>
        </groovy>
</target>
```

I am trying to run this script from Eclipse and as you can see script is calling Groovy class. When I execute this script all I get is the message saying that build file executed successfully and it runs for 1 second which tells me that class was not executed.

My class is the following:

```
public class Checkout{
def pomFile
def svnRoot
def svnProjectDir
def jenkinsWorkspace
def libDir
def queryFile
def ant

public static void main(String[] args) {
    pomFile = args[0]
    svnRoot = args[1]
    svnProjectDir = args[2]
    jenkinsWorkspace = args[3]
    libDir = args[4]
    queryFile = args[5]
    new Checkout()
}

def init(){
    ant = new AntBuilder()
    ant.typedef(resource: 'org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml'){
        classpath {
            fileset(dir: libDir, includes: '*.jar')
        }
    }
    ant.echo("INIT")
    pomFile = args[0]
    svnRoot = args[1]
    svnProjectDir = args[2]
    jenkinsWorkspace = args[3]
    libDir = args[4]
    queryFile = args[5]
    startCheckout()
}
```

I am not sure if I need to have main method, this is the only way I am able run this class from Eclipse. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Eclipse is sometimes the issue. Does it work from the command line?

Comment: @tim_yates I tried it, same thing. I am calling groovy correctly from ANT? Also when setting breakpoint I don't step into the code once ant script runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run a groovy script (`<groovy src=...`) together with inline groovy code. If you do it, the script is ignored and only inline code is executed.

You can verify it by switching

```
def checkoutClass = new Checkout()
checkoutClass.init = {-> true}
```

with

`println "hello"`

In order to execute your script, just remove those two lines above.

Your script code should look like this:

```
ant = new AntBuilder()
ant.typedef(resource: 'org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml'){
    classpath {
        fileset(dir: libDir, includes: '*.jar')
    }
}
ant.echo("INIT")
pomFile = args[0]
svnRoot = args[1]
svnProjectDir = args[2]
jenkinsWorkspace = args[3]
libDir = args[4]
queryFile = args[5]
startCheckout()
```